# Python formatted strings and datetime

Tags: python, datetime, formatted-text

Is this not allowed or did I type something wrong?

```
import datetime

print(f"Current Time: {datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%I:%M:%S %p")}"
```

```
Syntax error at %I:%M...
                  ^
```

Comment: You are using quotes `"` inside quotes. Try to escape them or use single quotes `'`

Comment: `print( datetime.datetime.now().strftime("Current Time: %I:%M:%S %p") )`

Comment: That's a lot to put in an f-string. Might be better to do it the old-fashioned way: `print("Current Time:", datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%I:%M:%S %p"))`

Answer (score 3):

You are ending your fstring by using double quotes in your `strftime()` function, use single quotes or escape them.

For example:

```
print(f"Current Time: {datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%I:%M:%S %p')}"
```

Also, not related to your question, but you are not really using fstrings in the right way.

It would look a lot nicer if you defined a 'current time' variable and then put it in your fstring.

For example:

```
current_time = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%I:%M:%S %p')

print(f"Current Time: { current_time }")
```

Answer (score 2):

Why not like this:

```
from datetime import datetime
    
print(f'Current Time: {datetime.now():%I:%M:%S %p}')
```

See [PEP498](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/#abstract).

Answer (score 0):

```
 print(f'Current Time: {datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%I:%M:%S %p")}')
```

Quotes bro.

Answer (score 0):

The datetime class already has a pre-configured date to string method : [strftime()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior)

So your code can look something like this :

```
import datetime

date_today = datetime.datetime.now()
date_today.strftime('%I:%M:%S %p')
```

Answer (score 0):

Its because of quotes. Here is workaround method and your original method.

```
import datetime
print (f'Current Time : {datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%I:%M:%S %p")}')


import datetime
d = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%I:%M:%S %p")
print(f"Current Time: {d}")
```